# Possible combinations - 4 columns with 10 distinct words

Tags: combinations

Even if there is a solution here, I can't find it, so apologies in advance. My problem is the following. I have 4 columns (A,B,C,D) that have 10 distinct words in them in rows 1-10. I was trying to calculate how many 4-word combinations there are when the condition is that only one word can be selected from each column.

One similar example that I found suggests that the answer might be 40*35*30*25*20, which equals 21 million, but I don't know if it's accurate as the number is quite large. Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: It should be $10^4$, what is the other example like?

Answer (score 1):

You may choose ten words from the first column. For each of those possibilities, you may choose from ten words from the second column, etc. This gives $10^4$ possibilities in total.